Хочу создать веб-приложение, чтобы его можно было установить на пк
Хочу создать веб-приложение, чтобы его можно было установить на пк, но не могу понять, как это сделать.
Как писать клиент? (например, это будет обычный фронтенд html/css/js)
Как соединить сервер и клиент?
Например, если кто-то знает, хотел бы знать сделаны десктоп программы Discord и Telegram и похожие. Они используют html или написаны с помощью ui библиотек?
И еще, можете подсказать, как искать в этом направление информацию, что нужно искать и гуглить по этому поводу.


Как писать клиент? (например, это будет обычный фронтенд html/css/js)

js electron если хочется творить на html
Discord на сколько я знаю вообще написан на python (могу ошибаться)

И еще, можете подсказать, как искать в этом направление информацию, что нужно искать и гуглить по этому поводу.

на ютубе миллион уроков, gpt как помощь в организации и структуры. Советую попробовать по очереди несколько вариантов (C, js, python) и выбрать понравившийся.


Как писать клиент?

Например с помощью электрона

В современных версиях Windows компанией Майкрософт используется браузер Microsoft Edge. Этот браузер умеет создавать из сайта "программу на компьютере".
Достаточно зайти на нужный сайт и с помощью пункта меню "Программы / Инсталлировать этот сайт как программу" (насчёт точных названий не уверен, у меня Windows на другом языке) создать такую программу. Такую программу можно сразу же найти в главном меню, её можно закрепить в Пуск, закрепить на панели задач, создать для неё ярлык на рабочем столе. При переустановке Windows такую программу можно легко восстановить, ибо список таких программ хранится в учётной записи Майкрософт. В браузере есть полноценный интерфейс для управления такими программами (добавление, удаление, сортировка).
Что такое они есть? Они практически ничего не занимают на диске, что не удивительно, ведь это сайты, запускаемые в режиме "киоск", их файлы хранятся там же, где приложения Магазина (по сути своей они похожи на такие приложения).
Многие компании, например, Facebook, распространяют свои приложения через Магазин, но по факту они именно приложения такого типа. У них даже есть название - PWA.
Постановка такой задачи - делать программу-веб-приложение - вчерашний день. Делайте сайт, полноценный и рабочий. А "программу" из него сделает за две секунды браузер Microsoft Edge.
Надеюсь, понятно, что всё это касается только ОС Windows, использующей полноценный браузер Microsoft Edge. О ситуации в других ОС с этим ничего не знаю, да и неинтересно.
Большая часть сайтов, которыми я пользуюсь, у меня сделана именно в таком виде, например: Google Gmail, Youtube.
Есть проблемы в таком варианте с Telegram и Whatsapp (это отдельная тема и она следствие исключительно криворукости писателей), поэтому я пользуюсь приложениями Магазина в этом случае. Но даже и в этом случае по факту эту веб-страницы, открытые в режиме "киоск".
